# How to make the system back arrow go downwards

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the orientation of the system back button located at the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to display the arrow going down the same way the Android system keyboard does?

Default state:
[image: Left orientation]

To (without the keyboard logo):

[image: Down orientation]

Comment: It is default with android lollipop. Do you want to achieve it somewhere else?

Comment: @VivekMishra Yes, I want to know if it's possible to do it programmatically.

Comment: I searched for it and didn't find any clue about it anywhere.Try asking it in android developer group in google plus.